# Updating many megabytes of vertex data per frame

Tags: gpu, webgl

I am investigating practical upper bounds for the amount of vertex data that I can upload to a WebGL 1 application using `bufferData` and `STATIC_DRAW`. I prepared a snippet that lets you adjust the number of triangles pushed per frame from 0 to 10'000'000. I am not using the more efficient `bufferSubData` and `STREAM_DRAW` options because I really want to experience the worst case. Also, I am drawing the triangles very small on screen so that the fill rate does not heavily influence the results.

```js
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 180;
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    
    const MAX_TRIANGLES = 10000000;
    
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Triangles to upload each frame: "));
    
    const range = document.createElement("input");
    range.type = "range";
    range.min = 0;
    range.max = MAX_TRIANGLES;
    range.value = 100;
    document.body.appendChild(range);
    let nTriangles = range.value;
    range.addEventListener("input", () => {
      nTriangles = range.value;
    });
    
    const mbPerFrame = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(mbPerFrame);
    
    const fps = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(fps);
    
    gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    
    const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, "attribute vec2 a_position; void main(void) { gl_Position = vec4(a_position / 100.0, 0.0, 1.0); }");
    gl.compileShader(vs);
    const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, "precision mediump float; void main(void) { gl_FragColor = vec4(0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05); }");
    gl.compileShader(fs);
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    
    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
    
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    const randomVertexData = new Float32Array(3 * 2 * MAX_TRIANGLES);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3 * MAX_TRIANGLES; i++) {
      randomVertexData[i * 2 + 0] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
      randomVertexData[i * 2 + 1] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    }
    
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    const frameTimes = new Set();
    
    function frame() {
      frameTimes.add(performance.now());
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(randomVertexData.buffer, 0, nTriangles * 3 * 2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, nTriangles * 3);
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    
    setInterval(() => {
      const now = performance.now();
      let framesLastSecond = 0;
      frameTimes.forEach((frameTime) => {
        if (now - frameTime < 1000) {
          framesLastSecond++;
        } else {
          frameTimes.delete(frameTime);
        }
      });
      
      mbPerFrame.innerText = `${Math.floor((nTriangles * 3 * 2 * 4 / (1024 * 1024)) * 100) / 100} MB per frame`;
      fps.innerText = `${framesLastSecond} FPS`;
    }, 1000);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

The render loop basically does this:

```
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(randomVertexData.buffer, 0, nTriangles * 3 * 2), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, nTriangles * 3);
```

Where `randomVertexData` is some data prepared in advance and `nTriangles` is controlled by the slider.

As you slide the slider right, you will see the size in MB increase and the frame rate drop.

On my machine (Dell laptop with i7 vPro and Quadro M1000) uploading 30 MB per frame still results in 60 FPS, which is more than enough for my application. On my smartphone (Motorola G7 Power), uploading 4 MB per frame still results in 60 FPS.

**Questions**

1. Did I design this performance experiment properly?
2. Can I trust/extend its results to the real world?
3. What do you think it a reasonable amount of data to push per frame for middle-end 2020 mobile devices and laptops?

Comment: It would be way more useful as a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) than a codepen. The site rules in essence say if the code you're asking about is not in the question itself then the question is off topic. You're asking if you're perf test is correct but the code for your perf test is not in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you @gman, awesome suggestion. I converted the code to a snippet. I was thinking that maybe 1) in itself is more of a CodeReview question, but the spirit of 1) 2) 3) as a whole fits StackOverflow better I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Did I design this performance experiment correctly

That depends on your definition of correct. `setInterval` is not guarantee to be remotely accurate but the code assumes you asked for 1000ms and you got 1000ms, not 1100ms or 900ms etc..  If it was me I'd not use `setInterval` and use the time passed into `requestAnimationFrame` and get a result over the the last 1 second of frames taking into account the actual time those frames took

> 2. Can I trust/extend its results to the real world?

I don't know what this question means. Every gpu/cpu/browser/driver may give a different results. You could try to match results to some fingerprint of the gpu/cpu/browser. Fingerprint might be as simple as user agent + WEBGL_debug_renderer_info info though not all browsers support WEBGL_debug_renderer_info or for that matter user agent.

> 3. What do you think it a reasonable amount of data to push per frame for middle-end 2020 mobile devices and laptops?

I don't know, I'd have to test a bunch of different devices and test on different browsers.

a few more comments on your test

- It's using `gl.STATIC_DRAW` but it should arguably be using `gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `gl.STREAM_DRAW` as this tells the browser/driver you'll be changing the data often (no idea which drivers use this info)
- This is driver dependent but for many drivers it's probably faster to allocate the buffer once and upload new data with `bufferSubData`. Semantically `bufferData` allocates memory and `bufferSubData` does not and generally memory allocation is slower than not-allocating though I've heard of cases where it's the opposite.
- If you only care about vertex upload speed then you probably want to draw your triangles as small as possible or possibly not at all (zero size triangle) so you can remove the drawing overhead. To put it another way, 1000 512x512 triangles will draw much slower than 1000 2x2 triangles because one is drawing 4000 pixels and the other is drawing 262 million pixels.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
    const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    
    const MAX_TRIANGLES = 10000000;
    
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Triangles to upload each frame: "));
    
    const range = document.createElement("input");
    range.type = "range";
    range.min = 0;
    range.max = MAX_TRIANGLES;
    range.value = 100;
    document.body.appendChild(range);
    let nTriangles = range.value;
    range.addEventListener("input", () => {
      nTriangles = range.value;
    });
    
    const mbPerFrame = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(mbPerFrame);
    
    const fps = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(fps);
    
    gl.clearColor(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    
    const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vs, "attribute vec2 a_position; void main(void) { gl_Position = vec4(a_position / 100.0, 0.0, 1.0); }");
    gl.compileShader(vs);
    const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fs, "precision mediump float; void main(void) { gl_FragColor = vec4(0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05); }");
    gl.compileShader(fs);
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program, vs);
    gl.attachShader(program, fs);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    
    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, MAX_TRIANGLES * 3 * 2 * 4, gl.STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 8, 0);
    
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    const randomVertexData = new Float32Array(3 * 2 * MAX_TRIANGLES);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3 * MAX_TRIANGLES; i++) {
      randomVertexData[i * 2 + 0] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
      randomVertexData[i * 2 + 1] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    }
    
    gl.useProgram(program);
    
    let then = 0;
    let numFrames = 0;
    
    function frame(now) {
      const elapsedTime = now - then;
      if (elapsedTime >= 1000) {
        then = now;
        
        mbPerFrame.innerText = `${(nTriangles * 3 * 2 * 4 / 1000 / 1000).toFixed(1)} MB per frame`;
        fps.innerText = `${(numFrames / (elapsedTime * 0.001)).toFixed(1)} FPS`;
        
        numFrames = 0;
      }
      ++numFrames;
      
      gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Float32Array(randomVertexData.buffer, 0, nTriangles * 3 * 2));
      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, nTriangles * 3);
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
```

Comment: Thank you. For STATIC vs DYNAMIC/STREAM as well as Data vs SubData it was intentional; I tried also DYNAMIC and Data and did not notice any difference on my machine. Maybe DYNAMIC and SubData would produce a noticeable change.

Comment: For the triangle size, I did not make it zero because I did not want some exotic driver optimizazion/trickery to kick in and start NOT uploading the buffer on every frame. But now I realize I was being paranoid, there is no way a driver could be so smart, and no reason to code such an optimization for such an edge case.